# How to print a PDF with large pages onto multiple smaller sheets of paper?

Tags: print-design, pdf

I have a PDF file containing a map with a page size of A0. How do I print it on A4 or A3 as tiles, which I can then stick together?

Comment: Hi Brett, interesting question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Have you tried googling? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: On Mac OS the default PDF viewer is Preview, but it doesn't seem to include this feature.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Discovered that in the print dialog in Adobe Reader there is an option called Poster under Page Sizing & Handling, which does exactly this. What's even better, you can print JUST ONE PART of your poster by zooming and resizing the window to show the bit you want to print BEFORE you press Print, then use Pages to Print > More Options > Current View.

Comment: Doesn't work under Linux, as Adobe no longer supports Reader for Linux (and the very old last installer doesn't seem to result in a working program).