# How do I convert a one page PDF file into several smaller (8.5" by 11") pages?

Tags: pdf, resize, print-production, digital-printing

#### There is a related question  already posted here

> [How to print a PDF with large pages onto multiple smaller sheets of ***paper***?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/55922/180598)

---

However, at the moment, we do not desire to print the picture out on ***paper***.

We desire the output to be a digital portable document format file (`.pdf`).

I do not want to use the "*poster print*" option in [Adobe Reader](https://Adobe%20Acrobat), because that is usually used to produce the end result as ink on paper.

In this case, we want an output `.pdf` file for which each page is 8.5 by 11 inches (21.59 by 27.94 centimetres).

The input file is quite large, maybe 3 feet wide.

Ideally, we could customize the settings. pages should have half white inch margins and one page could overlap another page by a 3/4 inch overlaps or margin

Answer (score 0):

We can still use Adobe Reader.

However, we will have to change to printer option to "**Microsoft Print to PDF**".

That way, the output is a `.pdf` file, not ink and paper.

[image: MICROSOFT PRINT TO PDF]